# How to run every slide in carouse Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developer back-end and not have experience about front-end, but current I have a problem with Bootstrap.
I found an example of carousel slider in BootstrapSnip.

It only skips one image when to click `next` button.

I want it to skip all image in a row.

In comment, it suggests:

```
// for every slide in the carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
```

But I don't know this mean. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Thanks.

To easy look please view my pen at:

> codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/EgPXXY?editors=1010

Or you can see code at bellow:

```js
// Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
   $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
  left: -33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .next {
  left: 33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
  left: -33%;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: none!important;
            transform: none!important;
  }
}
.multi-item-carousel .carouse-control.left,
.multi-item-carousel .carouse-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try out the [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for some of the best and easily customised carousels.

Comment: Your link reference look very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/aavrug/pen/YGwQjV) Just you have to do some changes in the markup.

```js
// Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
   $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
  left: -33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .next {
  left: 33%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
  left: -33%;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: none!important;
            transform: none!important;
  }
}
.multi-item-carousel .carouse-control.left,
.multi-item-carousel .carouse-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>

    <div class="well">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/item-->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/item-->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/item-->
            </div>
            <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
        <!--/myCarousel-->
    </div>
    <!--/well-->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you mention your change in this?

Comment: I found you change almost class at HTML in this repo. I think this only change JS.

Comment: I haven't changes anything in your CSS and js just a little tweak for your markup. previously you were displaying all the images one by one now it's little bit changed and few images in a row and then this sequence continued for three times.

Comment: Basically carousel is totally dependent on your markup. THis doesn't mean without js and CSS we can run but most of the things depend upon the markup.

Comment: Today, you helped me twice. Thank you for that.

Comment: Anytime, I am happy that I was able to solve your issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

See this link http://www.bootply.com/89193 and this one http://www.bootply.com/92514

I hope you will find something useful

Comment: Look very nice. Thanks @husainahmmed.

Comment: Your welcome @Van Loc

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this ink

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

goto to this and do inspect elements and you can find carousel slider.

In your code please checkout that you have linked JS and CSS to html file.

Comment: I not found anything your mention.